# Не работает JS в Yii2 - как поправить?

Tags: javascript, yii2, form

Есть код в `_form.php` вместе с целевой кнопкой `'submitButton'` которую необходимо сделать неактивной, пока пусты поля формы. JS пока написан для одного поля `'first_name'`:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Contact */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

$myJs = <<<JS
   $('#first_name').change(function() {
   $('#my_button').removeAttr('disabled');
   })
JS;

$this->registerJs($myJs);
?>

<div class="contact-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Имя <span class="note">* поле обязательно к заполнению</span>') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Фамилия <span class="note">* поле обязательно к заполнению</span>') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'middle_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Отчество') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'internal_phone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Вн.телефон <span class="note">* поле обязательно к заполнению</span>') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile_phone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Моб.телефон <span class="note">* поле обязательно к заполнению</span>') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Email адрес <span class="note">* поле обязательно к заполнению</span>') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Добавить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'test-button',
            'id' => 'my_button', 'disabled' => 'disabled', /*'onclick' => '$("#my_button").attr("disabled", "disabled")'*/]) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

assets/AppAsset.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main application asset bundle.
 *
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle

{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
//    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
}
```

1. Как всегда - кто виноват и что делать (в приложении к коду)?
2. Почему при варианте написания, указанном ниже, не опознается jQuery:

Ошибка:  `syntax error, unexpected token "(", expecting variable or "{" or "$"`

```
 $this->registerJs(
$('#first_name').change(function() {
   $('#my_button').removeAttr('disabled');
   })
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько помню тебе нужно было на несколько полей сделать проверку.

1. Выбираешь поля устанавливая класс inputNotNull:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Имя <span class="note">* поле обязательно к заполнению</span>') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Фамилия <span class="note">* поле обязательно к заполнению</span>') ?>
```

2. регистрируешь скрипт (лучше отдельным файлом, что бы можно было использовать в других местах. Но просто текстом тоже нормально:

```
function verifyNotNull() //функция проверки на пустоту
{
    if ($(this).val().trim()){
        $("#disabledBtn").prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $("#disabledBtn").prop('disabled', true);
    }

}

$(".posts-form").on("change", "input.inputNotNull", function (){ //накидываем обработчик событий на класс inputNotNull
    $('.inputNotNull').each(
        verifyNotNull
        ); // проверяем все инпуты в posts-form с классом inputNotNull на пустоту
});
```

Проверен. Работает.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, что написано в `registerJs` должно быть в виде строки!

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view#registerJs()-detail

```
public void registerJs ( $js, $position = self::POS_READY, $key = null )

$js - string - The JS code block to be registered
        ^---------
```

Потому что туда НЕ принимается какой-то callback.

Как следствие можно написать примерно так:

```
$js = <<<JS
    $('#first_name').change(function() {
       $('#my_button').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

а вообще, не проще ли испльзовать сразу теги `<script>`  или ассеты?

---

> кто виноват  ?

Виноваты вы, потому что не читаете доки! :))

---

> Почему при таком подходе всё равно не работает JS

Потому что на страницы нет элемента с id `first_name`

Если разработчик не указывает свой `id`, то `ActiveForm` генерирует его автоматически по формуле `strtolower(имя модели)-strtolower(имя атрибута)`

Например имя модели `TestLogicAction` а имя атрибута `func_type`, то будет сгенерирован идентификатор `testlogicaction-func_type`. Имя модели всё слитно.

Comment: 1. написал в одну строку код, который был написан в несколько строк - все осталось по-прежнему (с опозданием понял, что речь о типе данных - ок) 2. чем ваш вариант кода с heredoc отличается от моего? разницы не увидел 3. учу Yii2 поэтому регистрирую. тот же код в тегах `<script>` работает так же 4. как понять какой коллбэк не принимается. честно говоря, вообще не вижу в этом js коллбэка :( 5. виноват я - принимается. это неизбежно

Comment: @SimplyOne "чем ваш вариант кода с heredoc отличается от моего? " --- в моём варианте в метод `registerJs` передаётся строка, а у вас - нет. Вы же пытаетесь напосредственно код писать  не в виде **строкового литерала** если так яснее

Comment: подозреваю вы проглядели соответствующий код в первом блоке вопроса: ```$myJs = <<<JS
   $('#first_name').change(function() {
   $('#my_button').removeAttr('disabled');
   })
JS;

$this->registerJs($myJs);
?>```

Comment: @SimplyOne "Почему при варианте написания, указанном ниже, не опознается jQuery:" --- потому что надо писать как в самом начале писали. Почему так - ответ выше

Comment: Алексей, это я понял - спасибо что не поленились. вопрос-то в том, что и так не работает. и ошибок в консоли нет

Comment: @SimplyOne потому что на страницы нет элемента с id first_name?

Comment: точно. спасибо.
на случай, если забуду или задачку найдет такой же нуб - в html-коде браузера нашел id элемента, сформированный Yii2 (в моем случае `'contact-first_name'` - где `'contact'`, очевидно, название модели yii-проекта) и вставил его в код JS

Comment: @SimplyOne именно так. если разработчик не указывает свой id, то ActiveForm генерирует его автоматически по формуле `strtolower(имя модели)-strtolower(имя атрибута)`. Добавил в конец ответа

Comment: @SimplyOne Добавил в конец ответа чууууть более подробно

Comment: Алексей, если бы вы свои минусы сопровождали пояснениями чем вызвано ваше недовольство, у них был бы шанс оказаться полезными

Comment: @SimplyOne это к чему было написано?

Comment: ваше появление под топиками удивительным образом совпадает с поставленными минусами за них. в целом я не против, но хотелось бы конструктива

Comment: @SimplyOne это может быть кто угодно. Я не один на ресурсе

Comment: тем не менее вы это не отрицаете. поэтому свой коммент по-прежнему считаю уместным

Comment: @SimplyOne Кажется вы не умеете читать. Или анализировать написанное. Перечитайте моё предыдущее сообщение и сделайте правильный логичный вывод.

Comment: Алексей, я его уже сделал. поэтому вы и прочли написанное

Comment: @SimplyOne значит с логикой и рассуждением у вас явные проблемы.

Comment: Алексей, это всего лишь очередная ваша оценка, о которой вас не просили). но спасибо и на этом

Comment: @SimplyOne это констатация факта. Удачи в развитии

Comment: Алексей,  это вы по молодости так себя переоцениваете). удачи в развитии и вам

Answer (score 0):

в html-коде браузера нашел id элемента, сформированный Yii2 (в моем случае `'contact-first_name'` - где `'contact'`, очевидно, название модели yii-проекта) и вставил его в код JS. все заработало:

```
$myJs = <<<JS
   $('#contact-first_name').change(function() {
   $('#my_button').removeAttr('disabled');
   })
JS;
```

за подсказку в выявлении ошибки спасибо @Алексей Шиманский